# Get navigation bar title from selected row

Tags: uitableview, swift, title, navigationbar

I created a table view where the user is able to add rows by clicking an "add" button in navigation bar. When the user selects a row the app shows another table view. I want to set the title of the navigation bar to the name of the selected row.

I know how to set the title of the navigation bar if I pass the name to label in the second table view.

```
title = self.restaurant.name
```

But I haven't figured out how to pass it to the navigation bar without creating a extra label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually really easy. All you have to do is implement `prepareForSegue` and use `sender` to create an instance of UITableViewCell. From there you can easily get the title of that cell and using `segue.destinationViewController` you can set the nav bar title of the subsequent view controller.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell at row \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
        destinationVC.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```